# Owl Carousel 2 not working when CSS Grid is applied

Tags: html, css, css-grid, owl-carousel

I have an Owl Carousel that is working just fine with it's not in a CSS Grid container. As soon as I place it inside an HTML tag with the display set to grid it seems to not allow Owl to display properly and will for the slides to be side by side and it looks to be doubling them as well.

I set up a fiddle so you can see what I mean. If you remove the comments the grid CSS you will see Owl will span all of the slides at once.

```
<section>
<article>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="slide"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="slide"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="slide"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="slide"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="slide"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="slide"> Your Content </div>
  <div class="slide"> Your Content </div>
</div>
```

```
section{

  background-color: #000000;

 /*display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1,1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "slide-show";*/

  article{
    /*grid-area: slide-show;*/

   .owl-carousel{

      .slide{
          background-color: red;
          text-align: center;
          color: #fff;
          height: 500px;
      }
    }
  }

  }

    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        dots: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        autoplay: false,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            768: {
                items: 1
            },
            1400: {
                items: 1
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/icekomo/c0zrpg29/28/)

It seems to display all the slides, side by side, causing an excessive amount of horizontal scrolling. I've used this library a bunch, but I guess I've never tried to combine it with CSS Grid.

Comment: Your content must have height and if you don't apply it it will not be visible, can you share fiddle with exact issue?

Comment: I don't think it's a height issue.

Comment: Please share fiddle with your exact issue

Comment: The fiddle has the issue. Try to scroll left and you will see what I mean. But if you remove the CSS grid properties then Owl behaves as it should.

Comment: @Just Code, were you able to see the issue?

Comment: sadly no, I am expecting you to explain it clearly

Comment: Does the fiddle work? If you look at the fiddle, the screen on the bottom right, try to scroll to the right. You will see all the owl "slides" side by side. This is not how Owl typically works. But if you comment out the CSS grid properties you will see Owl work as it should.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone runs into this problem. If you are using CSS Grid with the Owl Carousel you need to set the parent element to have `min-width: 100%`.

Comment: That's a good catch! Thanks, but do you happen to know the underlying reasons for which CSS does this? I'm a diehard fan of CSS, but this is one of those things that makes me understand why some people hate it.